# MS SSRS Report Builder: Semantic query execution failed.?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, model

I have created an end user model and deployed it.  Any report that I create and run gives me an error:

Report execution error
The report might not be valid or the server
could not process the data.

### Semantic query execution failed. Invalid column name 'rowguid'.

### Query execution failed for data set 'dataSet'.

An error has occurred during report processing.

Most of the tables contain a primary key named, rowguid.  I cannot remove these from the data source views, but I did go in and removed them from the model.  This made no difference.

TIA 
Daniel

**Update**

The data source was in a folder for all of the reporting data sources.  As part of my testing/debugging I created a data source in the folder containing the model and the error went away.  I intend to initiate an MS support incident about this and will post the update here.

Answer (score 1):

Try Creating a view that either does not include that column.  Once you have done that recreate your data source views and model to be based on this view instead of the raw table and retry creating the report in Report Builder